# How to implement <apex:param> using dynamic visualforce components

Tags: dynamic-visualforce, apex-param

I am building an outputlink as a column as a part of pageblocktable all using dynamic visualforce components. But how do I build Param tag using dynamic visualforce components? I get an error when I compile this line of code - `Component.Apex.param paramInput = new Component.Apex.param();`

It seems Component.Apex.param is not a valid type.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: To help solve your problem, please provide the code you are using and the exact error message you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ashwani pointed out that `<Apex:param>` is not supported in dynamic respresentations, so I went for calling an action function Via `OnClick` attribute in dynamic representation.

```
String paramValue = '';
String paramValue1 = '';
...
...

paramValue = '{!result.Schedule_No__c}';
paramValue1 = '{!result.Client_ID__c}';
...
...
String onClickJSMethod = 'logAdditionalPSTransactionDetails(' + '\'' + paramValue + '\',\'' + paramValue1 + '\'); return false;';
Component.Apex.commandLink getLink = new Component.Apex.commandLink();
getLink.value = 'Get';
getLink.expressions.onClick = onClickJSMethod;
Component.Apex.Column columnLink = new       Component.Apex.Column(headerValue='');
columnLink.childComponents.add(getLink);
table.childComponents.add(columnLink);
```

Answer (score 1):

As per this document: [Dynamic Components Supported Attributes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_components_limitations.htm)

`<apex:param>` and few more attributes are not valid in dynamic components creation.

> The following standard Visualforce components don’t have corresponding
>   dynamic representations in Apex:
>
> ```
> <apex:attribute> 
> <apex:component> 
> <apex:componentBody> 
> <apex:composition> 
> <apex:define> 
> <apex:dynamicComponent> 
> <apex:include> 
> <apex:insert> 
> <apex:param> 
> <apex:variable>
> ```